# kernel-ranchu in Android 29

Tags: cordova, android-virtual-device

So I'm using `APACHE CORDOVA`, `without`Ionic`.

I created an **app** normally with the command at the **prompt**

**cordova create myApp br.com.carcleo myApp**

I created 2 `AVD's`, one for **Android 22** and another for **Android 28**.

For the **Android 22** the `emulator` works correctly. But for the **Android 28** **emulator** does not work.

It asks for `kernel-qemu` which should be in the **image** folder of `Android 28` but there is no such file there.

However, in the `Android 22` folder the file exists.

Well, there are 2 files with similar names, `kernel-qemu` and`kernel-ranchu`.
In this case, `Android 28` only has`kernel-ranchu`.

I even tried copying `kernel-qemu` from`Android 22` folders to the same folders on `Android 28`. `Android` even starts, but it stops on the black screen of the simulator and neither does the`Android` desktop show.

I've noticed the following: it looks for `kernel-qemu` in the`Android 28` folder. However, there is only this file in `Android 22` folder down.
In the `Android 23` folders, there is only the`kernel-ranchu`.

But what can be done to get around this problem? Should I make a build for the old version of `Android`? Was it just these the way out? Or do you have to edit **config.ini** to solve this? If so, how to proceed?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 4):

Even if this is old, for people googling for help and landing here, as of 2019 :

- Having modern versions of the emulator looking for this kernel-qemu is the "second chance" (using the old emulator mode, goldfish) when the emulator failed to boot with the prefered modern emulation mode (ranchu) and kernel version (kernel-ranchu).

For older Android versions system files files (like Android 22), kernel-qemu and kernel-ranchu were both available and working, in both "goldfish" and "ranchu" mode. And for scary old versions, kernel-ranchu wasn't available.

But kernel-qemu (used for "goldfish" mode) is a pretty out of date kernel kind (old emulation mode based on qemu 1). There is no up to date enough "kernel-qemu" kernels versions for booting modern Android versions into "goldfish mode" : goldfish mode support will be dropped soon or late.

**That being said :** it probably means that you have a problem with the Android 28 (9.0.0) emulator, something makes "ranchu" mode and associated kernel unable to boot on this version, on your machine, with your current files.

It's really simple to check if you can do something or not (there is very few things to know/check/reset about the emulator to make sure you tested everything). Debugging can be done this way :

- Go to c:\Users\Username.android\avd\
- For each created AVD, you have one *.ini file and one subfolder
- into the subfolder, delete everything apart from config.ini file : if one of those files is corrupt or stuck, it won't be able to work. If it's deleted, it creates fresh new ones. You can always take a look at what's inside config.ini if you want.
- You can run the emulator from command line :

  - C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator.exe @ExampleName (-engine qemu2)
  - or even, for goldfish mode, or more debug informations, additional parameters are available
  - C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator.exe @ExampleName -verbose -show-kernel -engine classic

Finally, if your system-image files (link into config.ini) are corrupt, you can delete them, delete all your AVD files, and clean downloading, creating and starting again your AVD.
In my case, my hardware is just unable to work fine with the emulator (HAXM bugs and too old CPU). But it works in Linux (but without KVM support : very slow).