# android AVD arm wont start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-image

I want to use AVD with arm system image to do some testing 
problem is none of the images I select `arm64-v8a , armeabi-v7a`
whether I select android 7 or 5 the AVD won't start up

error log

```
10:39 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.

10:39 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

10:39 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

tried all the images all gives same issue .

please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your SDK tools are up to date.

`ranchu` is the name of type of emulator
`goldfish` is the older alternative

If just updating doesn't work, then you need to ensure that the emulator version (aka ranchu/qemu) matches the Android version that supports it.

Android 5 (Lollipp[) should support Goldfish & Ranchu though, thats why I think an update is needed.

[image: aosp versions]

References:

[kernel-ranchu in Android 29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347866/kernel-ranchu-in-android-29)

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file/9723/3

Comment: @Mr.Zex If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers